# sublimetext typescript package does not work on .js files

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

I'm using the https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript package with sublimetext.  I noticed that go to definition and all does not work if the file extension is .js.  However if I change the file extension to .ts then the same command works and navigates into the .d.ts file for any npm modules. Is there some way I can fix this?

Comment: If I recall correctly the Microsoft TypeScript package does code analysis on its own to know where symbols are but it only does it for TypeScript files; JavaScript files would then use the built in functionality for that which isn't as focused. If there's not a setting in the TypeScript package, there may not be a way to get it to apply.

Comment: Thats what I also thought, there might be some setting, but could not find any.